# Assign value using multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, apply

I would like to apply a function that consists of classification rules to assign a value of high, medium, and low risk to a new column based one each participant's gender, age, and race.

Let's assume this is my `df`

```
   gender age      race
1    male  11 NON_WHITE
2    male   9     WHITE
3  female  36 NON_WHITE
5  female   3     WHITE
6  female  81     WHITE
7  female  14 NON_WHITE
8  female  14 NON_WHITE
9  female  79 NON_WHITE
10   male  44     WHITE
```

I'd like to assign a value based on gender, age, and race. For example:

High = female; any-age; NON_WHITE OR male; >=70; NON_WHITE

Medium = female; >=75; WHITE OR male; <70; NON_WHITE

Low = female; <75; WHITE OR male; any-age; WHITE

The result would be a value assigned to `df$class`:

```
  gender age      race   class
1    male  11 NON_WHITE  Medium
2    male   9     WHITE     Low
3  female  36 NON_WHITE    High
5  female   3     WHITE     Low
6  female  81     WHITE  Medium
7  female  14 NON_WHITE    High
8  female  14 NON_WHITE    High
9  female  79 NON_WHITE    High
10   male  44     WHITE     Low
```

I wrote a function and applied it to the dateframe:

```
Riskfun <- function(x) { 
if(x["gender"] == "female" & x["race"] == "NON_WHITE") 
    df$class <- "HighRisk"
if(x["gender"] == "male" & x["age"] >= 70 & x["race"] == "NON_WHITE") 
    df$class <- "HighRisk"
if(x["gender"] == "female" & x["age"] >= 75 & x["race"] == "WHITE") 
    df$class <- "MediumRisk"
if(x["gender"] == "male" & x["age"] < 70 & x["race"] == "NON_WHITE") 
    df$class <- "MediumRisk"
if(x["gender"] == "female" & x["age"] < 75 & x["race"] == "WHITE") 
    df$class <- "LowRisk"
if(x["gender"] == "male" & x["race"] == "WHITE") 
    df$class <- "LowRisk"
 }
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: @jogo would you believe me if i told you that I hadn't been able to find your weblink for the past hour? haha

Comment: Note that you don't need to do 6 `ifelse` statements. `|` is used as `or`. i.e. `ifelse(df$gender == 'female' & df$race == 'NON_WHITE' | df$gender == 'male' & df$age >= 70, 'High', ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            You can use for loop element wise

            for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
              data$class[i]<-ifelse(data$gender[i]=="female"&data$race[i]=="NON_WHITE"|data$gender[i]=="male"&data$age[i]>=70, "High", "LOW")
              data$class[i]<-ifelse(data$gender[i]=="female"&data$age[i]>=75&data$race[i]=="WHITE"|data$gender[i]=="male"&data$age[i]<70 &data$race[i]=="NON_WHITE", "Medium", data$class[i])
              data$class[i]<-ifelse(data$gender[i]=="female"&data$age[i]<75&data$race[i]=="WHITE"|data$gender[i]=="male"&data$race[i]=="WHITE", "Low", data$class[i])
            }

 **Or use if statement in the loop rather than ifelse, both codes gives the same result**

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(data$gender[i]=="female"&data$race[i]=="NON_WHITE"|data$gender[i]=="male"&data$age[i]>=70){
  data$class[i] <- "High"}
  if(data$gender[i]=="female"&data$age[i]>=75&data$race[i]=="WHITE"|data$gender[i]=="male"&data$age[i]<70 &data$race[i]=="NON_WHITE"){
  data$class[i] <- "Medium"}
  if(data$gender[i]=="female"&data$age[i]<75&data$race[i]=="WHITE"|data$gender[i]=="male"&data$race[i]=="WHITE"){
  data$class[i]<- "Low"}
  }

    print(data)
         gender age      race  class
        1   male  11 NON_WHITE Medium
        2   male   9     WHITE    Low
        3 female  36 NON_WHITE   High
        4 female   3     WHITE    Low
        5 female  81     WHITE Medium
        6 female  14 NON_WHITE   High
        7 female  14 NON_WHITE   High
        8 female  79 NON_WHITE   High
        9   male  44     WHITE    Low
```

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized. No need for a loop.

Comment: Can"t we use the same code for the above one